# scala проект encoding

Tags: кодировка, scala

На *Idea* создал *SBT* проект в нем создал `test.sc` так вот когда запускаю вместо русских символов там `???`. Потом я написал:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

а там выводить что:

```
res0: String = Cp1252
```

как поменять на UTF-8??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал системную переменную `JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"` b и теперь в командной строке правильно выводить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в *IDEA* все еще `cp1252`. 
Кто нибудь знает как исправить?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где можно ставь UTF-8.
Смотри:

- Правый нижний угол
- Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) -> File Encodings

Можешь еще попробовать добавить в `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions := Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8")
```